# What is needed to stop the Sub from running it seems to run for a long time?

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving an "Overflow" message.  The code is working as expected, but is running for a long time.  Any suggestions.

```
Sub Bill_Detail_Exp_Prem_Var()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

    LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Detail").range("C:C").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 7 To LastRow
        If wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 15) <> 0 And wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 16) = 0 Then
            wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 1) = ((wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 15)))
        Else
            wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 1) = ((wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 17)) * (wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 15))) / (wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 16))
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: what value does `LastRow` have?

Comment: Is there a chance that `wb1.Sheets("Detail").cells(i,16)` can ever be zero? Actually, I can see from your code  that it can. Did you perhaps intend to have `Or` instead of `And` in your first if-statement?

Comment: and what value does `i` have when it throws the error?

Comment: I use LastRow to stop at the lastrow of data.  Not or because both need to be true.  i has the value of approximately row  65010.  I use this same format in a Sub for previous column and it stops as expected.  Lastrow for some reason has value of 65010 but no data is in the sheet even close to that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this valid?

```
LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Detail").range("C:C").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

should it not be

```
LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Detail").range("C:C").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: Might want to include an `, After:=Range("C1")` in case the active cell is not C1.

Answer (score 1):

Your check

```
If wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 15) <> 0 And wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 16) = 0 Then
```

Does not check for both of these being equal to zero. The error `Overflow` does in fact happen when you do `0/0`.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("C:C").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 7 To LastRow
    Dim destinationCell As Range
    Set destinationCell = wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 1)
    Dim parameterFifteen, parameterSixteen, parameterSeventeen

    parameterFifteen = wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 15)
    parameterSixteen = wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 16)
    parameterSeventeen = wb1.Sheets("Detail").Cells(i, 17)

    If parameterFifteen <> 0 And parameterSixteen = 0 Then
        destinationCell = parameterFifteen
    ElseIf parameterSixteen <> 0 Then
        destinationCell = parameterSeventeen * parameterFifteen / parameterSixteen
    Else
        'something else ?
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Good catch (despite the extra *s*)!

Comment: @Jeeped snot...hehe oops